# Postgresql trigger check if NULL

Tags: postgresql, triggers, plpgsql

I have a table where rows described by an unique ID are meant to be updated from an automatic process on a regular bassis.

```
INSERT INTO mytable(x,y,z) ON CONFLICT(x) DO UPDATE SET y=A...
```

USE CASE :
Some rows do not have a value yet, the next cycle might set some values.
Other rows already have values, but the next cycle might have NULL values to update. In this case, I don't want the NULL values to replace the current values.

I created this trigger :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.clean_update()
    RETURNS trigger
    LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
    COST 100
    VOLATILE NOT LEAKPROOF
AS $BODY$
BEGIN

    NEW.company = COALESCE(NEW.company,OLD.company);
    NEW.first_name = COALESCE(NEW.first_name,OLD.first_name);
    NEW.last_name = COALESCE(NEW.last_name,OLD.last_name);
    NEW.address = COALESCE(NEW.address,OLD.address);
    NEW.country = COALESCE(NEW.country,OLD.country);
    NEW.phone = COALESCE(NEW.phone,OLD.phone);
    NEW.mail = COALESCE(NEW.mail,OLD.mail);
    NEW.evaluation = COALESCE(NEW.evaluation,OLD.evaluation);
    NEW.positive = COALESCE(NEW.positive,OLD.positive);
    NEW.neutral = COALESCE(NEW.neutral,OLD.neutral);
    NEW.negative = COALESCE(NEW.negative,OLD.negative);
    NEW.nb_products = COALESCE(NEW.nb_products,OLD.nb_products);
    NEW.nb_sales = COALESCE(NEW.nb_sales,OLD.nb_sales);
    NEW.nb_sale_url = COALESCE(NEW.nb_sale_url,OLD.nb_sale_url);
    NEW.unregistered = COALESCE(NEW.unregistered,OLD.unregistered);
    RETURN NEW;
END;
$BODY$;
```

With this trigger, the updated value is not replaced if its NEW.value is NULL, great.

The problem comes when updating only some of the columns :

```
ERROR:  record "new" has no field "nb_sale_url"
```

Is there a way to check if NEW.x exists event if it's null ?
Or maybe there is a simplier way to do it

Comment: Apparently your table does not have a column name `nb_sale_url`, so obviously you can't assign a value to it.

Comment: Add the actual trigger definition to your question. Also this:`INSERT INTO mytable(x,y,z) SET y=A ON CONFLICT(x) DO UPDATE SET...` make no sense, you can't `SET` in the `INSERT` portion.

Comment: You could catch the error.